# Funny error messages when compiling a C file

Tags: c, compilation

Um, I'm a bit new to C so I'm wondering as to why would it gives me the following error messages when compiling this lines:

```
   void (ESCALLBACK *drawFunc) ( void* );
   void (ESCALLBACK *keyFunc) ( void*, unsigned char, int, int );
```

For the first line it gives me:

> ```
>   error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
> ```

And for the second:

> ```
>   error: expected ‘;’ before ‘void’
> ```

It's quite possible that I am not giving you enough info, but for the moment I am wondering why would it print *such* error messages. I mean, they don't look very helpful and I don't think they even come close to the real problem here.

Sorry if I sound silly, I am a Java dev learning C.

Thanks!

Comment: You did somehow define `ESCALLBACK`, didn't you? Because if you didn't, these errors are normal: the compiler doesn't know ESCALLBACK is a type name if it hasn't been defined as a type (or a macro that expands to a type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably means that ESCALLBACK isn't defined and it's misparsing the rest of the line (and so giving you an unhelpful error).

Make sure you're including the header that defines ESCALLBACK.

Comment: Most probably is that. I'll look into it. Thanks! You see, I am not yet used to such unhelpful messages from the compiler :-D Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like it's [esutil.h](http://code.google.com/p/angle-fullscreen/source/browse/trunk/samples/gles2_book/Common/esUtil.h?spec=svn2&r=2), but that does define ESCALLBACK in place. If these errors are from compiling esutil.h then your compiler might not understand __cdecl :-/ If that's the case, which compiler?

Comment: GCC. Now then, I am actually trying to port the visual studio project made for windows to linux (using the appropriate headers and libraries).

Comment: Right - yes, that makes sense. Windows uses a mixture of calling conventions in its APIs e.g. `__cdecl` C-style (caller cleans arguments from stack), `__stdcall` Pascal-style (callee cleans), `__fastcall` some regs `__thiscall` C++ ecx=this etc. Linux generally doesn't - everyone uses cdecl which is actually default. So I'd suggest you just #define ESCALLBACK and ESUTIL_API to nothing, or delete them throughout. The exact GCC equivalent would be `__attribute__((cdecl))` but that's the default calling convention so it's easier to just omit it.

Comment: Yup, I did just that: `#define ESCALLBACK ` and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for the comprehensive info, too!